# Phpmailer image in email issue

Tags: php, macos, email, phpmailer

I don't know why in mail client of MAC OS X (Mail 6.2) the image display like this:

[image]

and other mail clients like gmail, outlook or private the image is correctly and looks like this:

[image]

**Phpmailer**

```
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); 

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Host       = "mail.com.mx";
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->CharSet    = "UTF-8";
    $mail->Username   = "soldier@mail.com.mx";
    $mail->Password   = "password?";
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@mail.com.mx', 'MA Consulting');
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $message = '<div style="border:solid 1px #427696;font-family:Arial;width:650px">
                <table style="background:#799db4;border-bottom:solid 1px #427696;width:650px; padding:5px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="padding:30px 30px 0;font-size:30px; height: 65px;">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;" href="iq.com.mx/iq" target="_blank">MA Consulting</a> 
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;padding-right:30px">
                                <img src="../media/Logo-MA.gif" width="120px" height="93px"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- more code -->';

    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
    $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing, since it's hard to test, but I don't think `width` and `height` attributes in `<img>` should include `px`.

Try to remove them:

```
<img src="../media/Logo-MA.gif" width="120" height="93"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize, just accept the answer and closed the tab

Comment: @SoldierCorp - you can un-do a downvote, if it was by accident.

Comment: But how? If when click up-vote, display this: "You last voted on this answer yesterday Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Comment: @SoldierCorp I edited my answer, you should be able to remove your downvote :)

Comment: Done :) and sorry one more time!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
width="120px" height="93px"
```

You're specifying `px` on the `width` and `height` attributes. That syntax is only relevant in CSS; the old style HTML attributes are always in pixels (or `%`), and `px` should not be specified.